Ask an identity on inner products
Question: how to get the the identity
$$
\left\|y_n-y_m\right\|^2=2\left\|x-y_n\right\|^2+2\left\|x-y_m\right\|^2-4\left\|x-\frac{y_n+y_m}{2}\right\|^2
$$
The background of the question is from the book Theoretical Foundations of Functional Data Analysis, with an Introduction to Linear Operators
by Randall L. Eubank and Tailen Hsing:

The following result is fundamental in optimization theory.
Let $\mathbb{M}$ be a closed convex set in a Hilbert space
$\mathbb{H}$. For every $x \in \mathbb{H},\|x-y\|$ has a unique
minimizer $\hat{x}$ in $\mathbb{M}$ that satisfies
$$ \langle x-\hat{x}, y-\hat{x}\rangle \leq 0 $$
for all $y \in \mathbb{M}$.
Proof: Our proof follows along the lines of that in Luenberger (1969).
First we observe that by the definition of infimum, we can obtain a
sequence $y_n \in$ $\mathbb{M}$ such that
$$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left\|x-y_n\right\|^2=\inf _{y \in
> \mathbb{M}}\|x-y\|^2 $$
The first step is to show that this sequence is Cauchy thereby
insuring that it converges to some element in $\mathbb{M}$. For this
purpose, we use the identity
$$
> \left\|y_n-y_m\right\|^2=2\left\|x-y_n\right\|^2+2\left\|x-y_m\right\|^2-4\left\|x-\frac{y_n+y_m}{2}\right\|^2
> $$
From convexity, $\left(y_n+y_m\right) / 2 \in \mathbb{M}$ and, hence
$$ \left\|y_n-y_m\right\|^2 \leq
> 2\left\|x-y_m\right\|^2+2\left\|x-y_m\right\|^2-4 \inf _{y \in
> \mathbb{M}}\|x-y\|^2 $$
Thus, $\left\{y_n\right\}$ is Cauchy and must have a limit $\hat{x}$
that attains the infimum. If there were another element $\tilde{x}$ in
$\mathbb{M}$ that also attained the infimum, we could create the
alternating series having $y_n=\hat{x}$ for $n$ even and
$y_n=\tilde{x}$ for $n$ odd. It is now trivially true that $\lim
> \left\|x-y_n\right\|^2=\inf _{y \in \mathbb{M}}\|x-y\|^2$ and our
previous argument can be used to see that the sequence is Cauchy. So,
it must have a limit and that can only be true if $\hat{x}=\tilde{x}$.
Suppose now that there is a $y \in \mathbb{M}$ for which $\langle
> x-\hat{x}, y-\hat{x}\rangle>0$. Then, if we let $x(a)=a y+(1-a)
> \hat{x} \in \mathbb{M}$ for $a \in(0,1)$, the derivative of
$\|x-x(a)\|^2$ at $a=0$ is negative. Thus, there is a choice of $a$
that makes $\|x-x(a)\|^2$
smaller than $\|x-\hat{x}\|^2$ which is a contradiction. On the other
hand, if $\langle x-\hat{x}$, $y-\hat{x}\rangle \leq 0$,
$$ \|x-y\|^2=\|x-\hat{x}\|^2+2\langle x-\hat{x},
> \hat{x}-y\rangle+\|\hat{x}-y\|^2 \geq\|x-\hat{x}\|^2 $$


Is "the following result" something you typed up from an outside source? If so, you should cite it (and make it clear it's not your own words, i.e. blockquotes). Anyway, I expect you just use the polarization identity $|a+b|^2=|a|^2+2\langle a,b\rangle+|b|^2$.

@coiso I update the question. Yeah, I know this identity. But I still do not get the answer.

This is just the parallelogram law applied to $x-y_n$ and $x-y_m$.

@Danny Can you give me a full answer?

You can use the parallelogram law
$$\|a-b\|^2+\|a+b\|^2=2(\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2)$$
(This is rather straightforward to check: expand the LHS using $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle$.) We have the expression
$$2\left\|x-y_n\right\|^2+2\left\|x-y_m\right\|^2-4\left\|x-\frac{y_n+y_m}{2}\right\|^2$$
Use the parallelogram law on the first two terms.
$$\|2x-(y_m+y_n)\|^2+\|y_m-y_n\|^2-4\left\|x-\frac{y_n+y_m}{2}\right\|^2$$
But the first and last term are equal, so we get $\|y_m-y_n\|^2$.
Hope this helps. :)

elegant. Thanks!
